# Postgresql jsonb query, which takes input of list with strings and compares all the records of table and need toreturn string matched coloumns

Tags: postgresql

I have a list of strings as input

```
["1234","919912931293,"99848566","54645364","265655644565","987987"]
```

And MY table Structure is (Jsonb)

1. `{"loginId": "+919912931293", "deviceUUID": "e7eb6355f043466d", "isReferral": false, "profileKey": "M00000h0PRFREG2015080122956987USS1"}`
2. `{"loginId": "+54564565", "deviceUUID": "e7eb6355f043466d", "isReferral": false, "profileKey": "M00000h0PRFREG2015080122zxcxcz987USS1"}`
3. `{"loginId": "+987987", "deviceUUID": "e7eb6355f043466d", "isReferral": false, "profileKey": "M00000h0PRFREG243543530122956987USS1"}`

Now I need a Single Query that takes input of list with strings and compares with "loginId" field in all the records in table if any of strings in list matches any coloumns of table just return those coloumns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `+` to each element of your list of strings, you can simply

```
select * from your_table_name where your_column_name->>'loginId' in ('+1234','+919912931293','+99848566','+54645364','+265655644565','+987987');
```